# I want to hide each div with the same class name as the id on click

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having an issue writing this jQuery code.

What I want is to be able to click the `option-menu` anchor tag and show the `div` with the class name of the same `id` so when I click `option1` I'll be able to see all the divs that have the class of `option1`

Menu

```
  <ul class="inline option-menu">
                <li><a href="#" id="option1">option1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="option2">option2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="option3">option3</a></li>
  </ul>


          <div class="cover option1">
                    <p>test 1</p>
            </div>
   <div class="cover option3">
                    <p>test 2</p>
            </div>
   <div class="cover option2">
                    <p>test 3</p>
            </div>
   <div class="cover option1">
                    <p>Tester 4</p>
            </div>
   <div class="cover option2">
                    <p>test 5</p>
            </div>
   <div class="cover option1">
                    <p>test 6</p>
            </div>
   <div class="cover option3">
                    <p>test 7</p>
```

Comment: I recommend spending an hour or two reading through [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It really only takes that long, and it provides a **huge** base of knowledge you can work from...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all of the elements whose `id`s start with `option` by using an [attribute-starts-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
$("[id^=option]")
```

You can handle clicks on them using [`.on("click", ...`](http://api.jquery.com/on) or just [`.click(...`](http://api.jquery.com/click)

Within that handler, `this` will be the DOM element that was clicked, so you can use `this.id` to get its `id`.

You can find elements with the relevant class using [`.` followed by the `id`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Since all of the options you want to hide have the class `cover`, that makes it easy to hide them and then show (or filter out) the ones you want to show.

So:

```
$("[id^=option]").on("click", function() {
    // Hide all
    $(".cover").hide();

    // Then show the ones that match this `id`
    $("." + this.id).show();
});
```

Or if you're adding and removing options often, probably better to use a delegated version:

```
$(document).on("click", "[id^=option]", function() {
    // Hide all
    $(".cover").hide();

    // Then show the ones that match this `id`
    $("." + this.id).show();
});
```

If you want, you can get a bit fancier using `.not` to avoid hiding elements inappropriately:

```
$(document).on("click", "[id^=option]", function() {
    var selectorToShow = "." + this.id;

    $(".cover").not(selectorToShow).hide();

    // Then show the ones that match this `id`
    $(selectorToShow).show();
});
```

Normally that doesn't matter much, but if you have CSS transitions on them or something...

Comment: What if the `id` is a different name and not `option` for each selection. For example the anchor has an id of `water` so the class name it would look for is `water` and another option would be `fire` it will look for classes `fire` right now it only looks for `option`

Comment: @BeEasy: Yes, because that's what your question said you wanted. If you're going to vary it, add a class to the links so we can select them with something other than the attribute-starts-with selector.

Comment: @BeEasy: Or alternately, select them with `$(".option-menu a")` if they're the only links inside `.option-menu`, or `$('.option-menu a[href="#"]')` if they're the ony `href="#"` links in it.